# Symfony 2 form associated entity with relation to the parent fails to save

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, associations

I am trying to follow this tutorial to have a many to many relation with join table as a form entity:
http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/07/symfnoy2-many-to-many-relation-with.html

In my case I have the following classes:

- Issue / User / AssignedUser

The AssignedUser entity is the join table between Issue and User.

In my form:

```
 $builder->add('assigned', 'entity', array(
            'required'  => false,
            'class'     => 'MyBundle:User',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true
        ));
```

My issue class. Omited some parts like namespaces.

(...)

```
        /**
         * 
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="(...)AssignedUser", mappedBy="issue",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
         *
         */
        protected $assignedUsers;

       /**
        * needed for the form to renders the users for select.
        */
        protected $assigned;


        public function getAssigned()
        {
            $assigned = new ArrayCollection();

            foreach($this->assignedUsers as $value)
            {
                $assigned[] = $value->getUser();
            }

            return $assigned;
        }


        // Important
        public function setAssigned($users)
        {
            foreach($users as $user)
            {
                $au = new IssueAssignedUser();

                $au->setIssue($this);
                $au->setUser($user);

                $this->addAssignedUser($au);
            }

        }

        /**
         * construct
         */
        public function __construct(){      
            $this->assignedUsers    = new ArrayCollection();      

            $this->assigned = new ArrayCollection();
}


 public function addAssignedUser($assignedUser)
    {
        $this->assignedUsers[] = $assignedUser;

        return $this;
    }
```

The problem lies with  setAssigned method.

```
   $au->setIssue($this);
```

My IssueAssignedUser:

```
/**
 * IssueAssignedUser
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="sup_issue_assigned_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ueb\Support\Bundle\IssueBundle\Entity\Repository\IssueAssignedUserRepository")
 */
class IssueAssignedUser
{


    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="...\Issue",inversedBy="assignedUsers",cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="issue_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false,onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $issue;


    /**
     * @var \Ueb\Accounts\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="...\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false,onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $user;


    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable
     */
    private $updatedAt;
```

I get the error:

> Entity of type ... IssueAssignedUser has identity through a foreign
>   entity Issue, however this entity has no identity itself. You have to
>   call EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure that
>   an identifier was generated before trying to persist

Is not suposed that doctrine persist the Issue entity first and only them try to persist the associated entities?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to persist the issue to the database before calling `setAssignedUsers()` on the issue.

```
$em->persist($issue);
```

Comment: For this to work i have to do like this:  $em->persist($entity);
               
                $em->flush();
          
                $assignedUsers = $form['assigned']->getData();
                $entity->setAssignedUsersFromForm($assignedUsers);
                
                $em->persist($entity);                                  I need to do two persists and two flush. is there any way I can do this automaticly with one perist/flush?

Comment: Because you are using `issue` as an id on your `IssueAssignedUser` entity, the id has to be know for `IssueAssignedUser` to persists. the `issue_id` is auto generated (auto increment) and this is generated by the database, so only available after a `flush()`. So yes, you are right you need to flush twice.